# Cannot connect to FTP server

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not able to connect to FTP server getting below error :-

```
 vmware@localhost ~]$ python try_ftp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try_ftp.py", line 5, in <module>
    f = ftplib.FTP('ftp.python.org')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 131, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

I'm writing a very simple code

```
import ftplib
f = ftplib.FTP('ftp.python.org')
f.login('anonymous','sausaxen@xyz.com')
f.dir()
f.retrlines('RETR motd')
f.quit()
```

I checked my proxy settings , but it is set to "System proxy setttings"

Please suggest what should I do.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[torxed@archie ~]$ telnet ftp.python.org 21
Trying 82.94.164.162...
Connection failed: Connection refused
Trying 2001:888:2000:d::a2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

It's not as much the hostname that's bad (ping works you mentioned) but the default port of 21 is bad. Or they're not running a standard FTP server on that host at all but rather they're using HTTP as a transport: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/

Try against **ftp.acc.umu.se** instead.

```
[torxed@archie ~]$ python
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 10 2014, 03:21:31) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140206 (prerelease)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ftplib
>>> f = ftplib.FTP('ftp.acc.umu.se')
>>>
```

Comment: It could also be related to that hostname server being unreachable over IPv6 from Sam's machine. He is getting an Unreachable, not a Refused (which would be expected and which is what I am getting).

Comment: @ikanobori Seeing as to how a IPv4 and IPv6 leads to the same machine, and the fact that this machine responds over IPv4 with a "Connection refused" I'd say they're not running a FTP server on this particular port. And there's no top google searches supporting that they've ever have so in conclusion, the user needs to switch methods or hosts.

Comment: Thanks a lot , ftp.acc.umu.se worked for , seems there is some problem with port itself

Answer (score 1):

The address `ftp.python.org` seems bad

EDIT:
 the `f = ftplib.FTP('ftp.python.org')` gives the error message but ping works.

Comment: Not so - pings fine from here.

Comment: It is pinging from my shell

Comment: The port is a factor also

Comment: indeed, pinging works, but the "f = ftplib.FTP('ftp.python.org')" gives the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging the "ftp.python.org" address.

If you need to pass through a proxy, check the you have `ftp_proxy` set as an environment variable. Normally, what I do is to set the proxy explicitly.

Also, as an alternative, try using httplib or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)